# Linux HTML/XML W3C Validation Utilities

Tags: html, validation, xml

What programs can I use to validate HTML/XML markup?

Basically, I want a local, command-line based, version of [W3C HTML validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) (like `lint`) that I can use for detecting errors.

**Update**

I would also accept a solution that uses the W3C web service from the command line.

**Related Questions:**

[How can I validate HTML offline?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/how-can-i-validate-html-offline)

Answer (score 4):

The W3 validator is [open source](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/) (written in Python I believe) so you can download and run it locally. I can't for the life of me find the download link on w3.org though.

Comment: I think this is it: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/markup-validator/

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/source/#getting

Comment: The W3C Markup Validator is a Perl wrapper around a C validation engine.

Answer (score 4):

[HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), developed by Dave Raggett of W3C, can validate & automatically fix errors. It can work from the [command-line](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tiptidy.html)

Comment: I like tidy, is it as comprehensive as the W3C tool?

Answer (score 2):

[Total Validator](http://www.totalvalidator.com/help/commandline.html) seems to do what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 validator source code is [available through SVN](http://about.validator.nu/#src), has dependencies on Java.

Comment: What do you mean by "the"? That's not an official program, is it?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat It's the only one linked to from the WHATWG website: http://validator.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the new [Linux command line tool htmlval for checking HTML and CSS](https://htmlval.com/?r=L).

Note: I'm the developer.

Testing this HTML (in file **example.html**):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<badtag>
<span>span has no end tag
</body>
</html>
```

With this command (**-l** for list format, **-S** for no SEO messages):

```
htmlval -lS example.html
```

Produces this error list:

```
=================================
=== File 1 of 1: example.html ===
=================================

Error (line 6, col 11): This document has a <title> element but it does not contain a title when it must. Each page on a site should have its own unique (never duplicated) and well-written title.

Error (line 9, col 2): The <badtag> element is not valid. Is it misspelled?

Error (line 10, col 2): The <span> element must have an end tag (</span>) but the end tag was not found, is misplaced, misspelled, or was not seen due to other errors.

Error (line 11, col 2): The end tag for <span> (started in line 10, column 2) should appear before this </body> end tag or this end tag should be deleted or moved. This is a nesting error.

Comment: "Errors and warnings only" mode enabled. Showing only error and warning messages (with some exceptions).
```

Comment: Thanks for the declaration and the development. Your answer would be great if you were to give a summary or screenshot of results.

Comment: @RohitGupta, thank you. I've added example input and output. I hope this is what you were wanting.